# Separate meshes with Solidify modifier

Tags: modifiers, solidify-modifier

When trying to prepare a mesh in Blender for display in the browser I need a solid model for my use case, where the inside and outside of the model have different UV mappings. My idea was to take an existing mesh and use the Solidify modifier to achieve this. However, when using the modifier I am unable to create two separately selectable meshes (or islands) which I can move into place in the UV editor.

The problem is that there seems to be no way to separately select the inside and outside of the mesh after I have applied the modifier. It always selects both sides when using the L-key. I tried applying different vertex groups and different materials but it only seems to be able to separate the rim from the in/outside in different groups, still not allowing me to select the inside and outside separately. There seems to be no easy way to select connected faces either (since they seem to be all connected) that I found.

For now I have limited success with the Displace modifier, create another object, move the UVs in this object out of the way, Join the two objects together again and then re-arrange the UVs as I want them.

Is there an easier way to achieve this? Is there an option in the Solidify modifier that I missed? I have been scratching my head about this for several days now, I hope somebody can help.

Comment: Select the whole rim by the materieal, than choose Select>>Loops>> Boundary Loop. Then Edge>>Mark Seam. After this you will be able to select with L or Ctrl+L Separately the two sides. (Only in face selection mode).

Comment: Or, if you selected the rim, hide it (H), then use L to select a side (and assign it to a vertex group).

Comment: @joshsanfelici -- do you imply that Alex should remove the Solidify Modifier before doing this?   I guess in Edit Mode it doesn't matter?

Comment: @james_t he said he applied it.